# Bulk loading Avro to HBase with NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm ingesting flowfiles containing Avro records with NiFi, and need to insert them into HBase.  These flowfiles vary in size, but some have 10,000,000+ records.  I use SplitAvro twice (one to split to 10,000 recs, then one to split to 1 rec), then use an ExecuteScript processor to pull out the row key for HBase and add it as a flowfile attribute. Finally I use PutHBaseCell (with a batch size of 10,000) to write to HBase using the row key attribute..

The processor that splits the Avro to 1 rec is very slow (Concurrent tasks is set to 5).  **Is there a way to speed that up? And is there a better way to load this Avro data into HBase?**

(I am using a 2 node NiFi (v1.2) cluster (made from VMs), each node has 16 CPUs and 16GB RAM.)

Comment: Please format your question and single out the question because it's a wall of text and it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: that is a really bad use for NiFI !

Answer (score 1):

There is a new PutHBaseRecord processor that will be part of the next release (there is a 1.4.0 release being voted upon right now).

With this processor you would avoid ever splitting your flow files, and you just send a flow file will millions of Avro records right to PutHBaseRecord, and PutHBaseRecord would be configured with an Avro reader.

You should get significantly better performance with this approach.